# How is better to track errors on React in Firebase using some crash reporting system?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I have a piece of code that catches errors from firebase response

```
...
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof FirebaseError) {
        switch (error.code) {
          case "auth/user-not-found":
            form.setErrors({ email: "No user with such email" });
            return;
          case "auth/wrong-password":
            form.setErrors({ password: "Wrong password" });
            return;
          default:
            // I want to save other cases in some error tracking system
            return;
        }
      }
      // I want also to save these error case in tracking system
      return;
    }
```

But I don't know if there is a better way to save these errors unless in Firestore directly.

How to better track errors in React and Firebase? Is there a way to use Sentry or any other crash reporting and monitoring system?

Comment: you can check all the error codes from link below
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors

Comment: Thanks. But it is a good idea to track an unknown error anyway. Imagine, it is not about firebase and you don't have error codes, but need to track errors to know what is going on on your project. How can it be done?

Comment: with all these errors cases you can handle any unexpected error which can be occur in project by using default case

Comment: Sure, I understand this. So now, is there a crash reporting system like sentry that I can use on firebase to save and review those?